# Is there a better way then a "KeyableShell" component?

Tags: reactjs, mapping

Consider a list like `titles`.

```
const titles = [
  <Title>Home</Title>,
  <Title>Search</Title>,
  <Title>Library</Title>,
  <Title>Profile</Title>,
];
```

If I `map` titles like this:

```
titles.map((title, index) => title);
```

I cannot give them a `key`. For this purpose I created `KeyableShell`.

```
function KeyableShell(props: KeyableShellProps) {
  const { children } = props;
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

So I can:

```
titles.map((title, index) => (
  <KeyableShell key={index}>{title}</KeyableShell>
));
```

Is there a better way than my solution?

Comment: Because if I don't put a key on the mapped components React throws a warning. I figured using a React fragment is the most efficient way to make mapped components "keyable" since they don't really have any HTML associated with them.

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood. I use fragments not to mess up any CSS and my thought process is that fragments are more efficient because they do not display any HTML.

Comment: I am sorry i take back what i said. This is probably what you are looking for `<Fragment>` https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#rendering-a-list-of-fragments

Comment: Put it in an answer, this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs, make the array with your titles  `const titles=["Home", "Search", "Library", "Profile"]` and map it. 
titles.map((title) => (
  <Title key={title}>{title}</Title>
));
Using index as key, is not recommended. and not best practics

Comment: @ClusterH that would not fit my use case, because I receive parameterized components.

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs man you are too kind, thanks for making my day :)

Comment: @TaiweiTuan you helped me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for --

https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment#rendering-a-list-of-fragments

Example from the official doc

```
function Blog() {
  return posts.map(post =>
    <Fragment key={post.id}>
      <PostTitle title={post.title} />
      <PostBody body={post.body} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```